# How to initialize a object with values in component Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to initialize my object with values that comes from my backend.
So on `ngOninit` I can bring my data values from service, but I'm don't know how to Initialize this object from component with this values. I need this values to show in a select from template, so this values has to initialize when the template renderize.

[Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if0Of.png)
[`ngOnInit`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51j1F.png)
[select from template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71RNm.png)
[console.log from `ngOnInit` of component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWCjF.png)

I tried to change the types from model but it's not works. When I mock this datas it's work.

Comment: You need to use `Observable` or Component Store. Please write more details of your component. I'll give you  more correct answer.

Comment: Please include your template code as well. Can't give a good answer without that. Please also paste the code into the question rather than linking to external image.

Comment: @Geo242 that's my template:

[template]https://prnt.sc/x2LdfQtnWsRn

Comment: @VajiloToram, I tried to do a method with `Observable` but I'm getting a error:

[code error] https://prnt.sc/_aTWjD0HnVKH

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You try to iterate over `deposit.nameBank` which is the attribute you want to store the selected value in. Instead you should iterate over the banks array

Comment: Thank you @SaschaA1982. 
I changed `deposit.name` by `banks`  in directive `ngFor` and worked.